# when i launch the activity the switch is working fine but it still goes off when the activity is going to backhand?

Tags: android, uiswitch

I recently worked in the project for making screen dimmer app but I stuck with one problem. In my app, there is **MaterialAnimatedSwitch** it works fine but when the app goes to the backhand, the switch is automatically off but the working of the app is perfectly continued. I want that the switch remains active or on whenever the user come back to the app interface.I use MaterialAnimatedSwitch so how to do this task.
i want the switch to be active or ON whenever the app resumes.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
int b1 = 40;
int b2 = 90;
DiscreteSeekBar bSeekBar;
ChatHeadService binder=null;
boolean isOn = false;
boolean mBounded;
public boolean isRunning=false;
ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        mBounded = false;
        mService = null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        mBounded = true;
        LocalBinder mLocalBinder = (LocalBinder) service;
        mService = mLocalBinder.getServerInstance();
        int brightness = mService.getBrightness();
        int brightness2 = mService.getBrightness2();
       seekBar.setProgress(brightness);
        bSeekBar.setProgress(brightness2);
    }
};
ChatHeadService mService;
RadioGroup radioGroup;
DiscreteSeekBar seekBar;
MaterialAnimatedSwitch aSwitch;
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Fabric.with(this, new Kit[]{new Crashlytics()});
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initInstances();
    if (isOn && !isMyServiceRunning(ChatHeadService.class)) {
        startService(new Intent(this, ChatHeadService.class));
    }

}



 private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : ((ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private void initInstances() {
    sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    seekBar = (DiscreteSeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    bSeekBar = (DiscreteSeekBar) findViewById(R.id.brightnessSeekBar);
    int b = sharedPrefs.getInt("b", 40);
    int bb = sharedPrefs.getInt("bb", 90);
    seekBar.setProgress(b);
    bSeekBar.setProgress(bb);
    aSwitch=(MaterialAnimatedSwitch)findViewById(R.id.switch1);
    aSwitch.setClickable(sharedPrefs.getBoolean("isOn",false));
    aSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(boolean b) {
            if(b){
                sharedPrefs.edit().putBoolean("isOn", true).apply();
                isOn = true;
                isRunning=aSwitch.isChecked();
                startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChatHeadService.class));
                bindService();
            }
            else{
                sharedPrefs.edit().putBoolean("isOn", false).apply();
                isOn = false;
                unBindService();
                stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChatHeadService.class));                }
        }
    });
    seekBar.setOnProgressChangeListener(new OnProgressChangeListener() {

        public void onProgressChanged(DiscreteSeekBar seekBar, int value, boolean fromUser) {
            b1 = value;
            if (mService != null) {
                mService.setBrightness(value, b2);
            }
            sharedPrefs.edit().putInt("b", value).apply();
        }

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(DiscreteSeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(DiscreteSeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });

    bSeekBar.setOnProgressChangeListener(new OnProgressChangeListener() {

        public void onProgressChanged(DiscreteSeekBar seekBar, int value, boolean fromUser) {
            b2 = value;
            if (mService != null) {
                mService.setBrightness(b1, value);
            }
            sharedPrefs.edit().putInt("bb", value).apply();
        }

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(DiscreteSeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(DiscreteSeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });

}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (isOn) {
        bindService();
    }
}

public void bindService() {
    bindService(new Intent(this, ChatHeadService.class), mConnection,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

public void unBindService() {
    if (mBounded) {
        unbindService(mConnection);
        mBounded = false;
    }
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    isRunning=aSwitch.isPressed();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(!isOn == aSwitch.isPressed()){
        aSwitch.toggle();
    }
}
```

}

Thanks in advance!

[This is the screenshot when app is just open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzXxS.jpg)

[This is the screenshot when night mode is ON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOgrJ.jpg)

[But When the going to backhand and then open the switch state changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0CNU.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest store value of your switch in one of your global variable and at time resume set it with the switch again like below:

```
public boolean isRunning = false;

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        isRunning = switchAler.isChecked();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        binding.switchAler.setChecked(isRunning);
        if(!isRunning == switchAler.isChecked()){
            switchAler.toggle();
        }
    }
```

Comment: when i use setChecked(isRunning) to store the state of MaterialAnimatedSwitch it gives an error saying unresolved symbol setChecked and also isChecked() is not applied to save the state.please suggest some idea to fix this.

Comment: I think the isChecked() is not working for MaterialAnimatedSwitch ,this code is also not working ,I think the setClickable() method works or not i'm applying but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You are saving switch state in Shared preferences but not using it.

just add the following line above `aswitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener`
 line, it will apply the state you saved in preferences

```
aSwitch.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean("isOn", false)); //false default
```

Comment: setChecked() is not working it gives error saying unresolved symbol.I want that the switch remains on when the activity resumes.

Comment: where are you adding this at? can you post the code?

Comment: I'm adding this code above the aSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener but  the setChecked() method  is giving an error than I use isChecked()  but my problem is not resolved by this isChecked() method. What I do??

Comment: can you please post your code instead of images. also post your error logs too

Comment: why are you using aSwitch.setClickable(sharedPrefs.getBoolean("isOn",false));  "setClickable" I suggest you to use setChecked

Comment: also what library you are using for MaterialAnimatedSwitch ??

Comment: But "setClickable" gives an error states not resolved.

Comment: "import com.github.glomadrian.materialanimatedswitch.MaterialAnimatedSwitch" I'm using this package